# How to calculate sliding Day by day count over the year SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have to calculate the sliding total of active users day by day last two years (2019 and 2020).
I have date, email and last visit columns.
Active users is active if last_visit > current day - 90.
First problem I met is that I don't know how to tell SQL what is my current day. I tried to use date column, but it brings en error and the same number of rows as before:

```
 WITH users_list as
  (SELECT SUBSTRING([agent_email], CHARINDEX('@', [agent_email])+1, LEN([agent_email])) AS DOMAIN,
          SUBSTRING(last_visit, 1, +10) as _date,
         VS.agent_email,
         VS.last_visit,
         vs.agent_license_type,
         vs.custom_templic
  FROM test.visitor AS VS
  WHERE VS.id NOT LIKE '%@rule.com'
    AND VS.agent_company NOT LIKE '%Rule%'
    AND last_visit> _date - 90
  GROUP BY VS.agent_email,
           VS.last_visit,
           vs.agent_license_type,
           vs.custom_templic
```

The second problem I don't know how to calculate the sliding Total of active users across 2019 and 2020. I Tried with this script:

```
SELECT _date, 
   count (agent_email)
   over(order by _date ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as number_of_active_users
FROM users_list
```

But it brings an error too.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...? The answer is very likely vendor-specific.

Comment: It is Amazon Redshift. Tag is added.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Redshift doesn't support the `range` window frame specification for dates.

Your sample code implements logic that is not in your problem description.  This answer is directed at the problem description.

So, an alternative method is keeping track of when users are in the range and not in the range.  This starts by determining the ranges for each user which is a gap-and-islands problem:

```
select test_email, min(last_visit) as active_start,
       max(last_visit) + interval '90 day' as active_end
from (select v.*,
             sum(case when prev_last_visit > last_visit - interval '100 day' then 0 else 1 end) over
                 (partition by test_email order by last_visit) as active_period
      from (select v.*,
                   lag(last_visit) over (partition by test_email order by last_visit) as prev_last_visit
            from test.visitor v
           ) v
     ) v
```

Then, with this information, we can unpivot to keep track of when someone enters an active state and leaves.  So:

```
with actives as (
      select test_email, min(last_visit) as active_start,
             max(last_visit) + interval '90 day' as active_end
      from (select v.*,
                   sum(case when prev_last_visit > last_visit - interval '100 day' then 0 else 1 end) over
                     (partition by test_email order by last_visit) as active_period
            from (select v.*,
                         lag(last_visit) over (partition by test_email order by last_visit) as prev_last_visit
                  from test.visitor v
                 ) v
           ) v
      )
select dte,
       sum(inc) as change_on_day,
       sum(sum(inc)) over (order by dte rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as actives_on_day
from ((select test_email, active_start as dte, 1 as inc
       from actives
      ) union all
      (select test_email, active_end as dte, -1 as inc
       from actives
      )
     ) a
group by dte;
```

If you want to filter this for a date range, use an addition subquery or CTE with the filtering in the outermost query.